# 3rd Party WinForm .NET Grid Controls

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview, controls

Anybody have any experience with 3rd Party WinForm .NET grid controls?

Before I spend the afternoon downloading and trying out several of the grids and/or control packs, anybody have opinions on vendors? functionality? etc.

Some of the ones I'll be looking at are:

- XCeed Grid
- Telerik Grid - Part of RadControls for WinForms
- Infragistics NetAdvantage WinClient for WinForms

Any reviews online? Comparison charts?

Answer (score 3):

This will undoubtedly get closed as subjective, but I'll go ahead and throw my full, unqualified support behind the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/DXperience/) suite of controls, specifically the XtraGrid. I have never worked with another control that had as much speed, customizability, and both reliable and robust designer support.

I'm using Telerik in my current job, and while the version I have now is lightyears better than the version I started with, I still don't think it holds a candle to DevExpress's offering.

Comment: Any specifics to what makes the DevExpress Grid more robust? Any killer features that it has and Telerik doesn't?

Comment: DevExpress is better on winforms and Telerik is better on ASP.Net suite controls. I have used both the control suites and can surely say that from my experience.

Comment: I agree with @Vikram. DevExpress's grid for WinForms is great, but you can also check out [NOV WinForms Grid](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-winforms-grid-overview.aspx) by Nevron. It is very fast and feature rich and is also available as a cross-platform Portable Class Library (PCL). _Disclosure: I work for Nevron_.

Answer (score 2):

Our experience with ComponentOne's C1 grid is just terrible. It blew up on our face when customers in the US government had FIPS policy in place and their customer support merely informs us - "yes, you are right, we are not FIPS compliant". Thank you very much and apart from that, the so-called virtual mode is just no good for large data.

Comment: what is FIPS? never heard of that

Comment: Federal Information Processing Standards ! There is a policy setting which prevents .NET from allowing the instantiation of anything that uses "banned" hashing algorithms like MD5 etc ! And all the US Government installations set up this system policy... ComponentOne confirms the problem, have no solution and do not seem to think that US Government policies matter to their customer's business.

Answer (score 2):

We use PFGrid for .NET, it's light-weighted but really powerful:

http://www.pfgrid.com

Answer (score 1):

I use Infragistics. It's very powerful, but can be difficult to set up for simple tasks. I haven't experienced any major problems or bugs. Their forums are pretty good for support, and they release updates quarterly (with serious bug fixes available more frequently).

Comment: Agreed with all points here - the documentation is not great, the source code sometimes hard to read and is full of developer comments about a bugfix and a date, but you can do pretty much anything iwth the infragistics grid.  Very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is reasonable to say that the time to learn any of the powerful grid controls is long enough that you are most often more productive in the one you know best.

Then there is the question of the “type” of data you are trying to display and:

- If you using DataSets
- Customs objects with data binding
- Or Just adding rows using the API

As very few people have extensive day to day experience of using the most recent version of more than one grid control in all the different styles of usage, we are not likely to get a useful answer to this question.

Trying  trial versions have the same problem, as you need to spend so many days on each grid before you can decide if you like the grid’s API.

So far the best option I have found it to try using one of the grids and ask the vendors support questions as you go along, I think the standard of support may be more important than the standard of the grid itself, as all the leading vendors have reasonable grid controls.   **Finding a vender with responsive support in the same time zone as you may be the best deciding factor.**

Answer (score 0):

Component one's C1.FlexGrid is quite handy. If you're not looking to spend any money, the built in grid in 3.5 is quite useful.

Comment: I'm looking for something that makes it ridiculously simple to do nested controls, validation, and grouping/sorting. Extra features are nice.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: look at [10Tec iGrid.NET](http://10tec.com/winforms-grid/). If you worry about learning curve, this is not the case for iGrid. Just a code example to setup a grid with 2 columns, 4 rows, place "abc" in the first cell and format it with red:

```
IGrid1.Cols.Count = 2
IGrid1.Rows.Count = 4
IGrid1.Cells(0, 0).Value = "abc"
IGrid1.Cells(0, 0).ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Has also cell styles you can use to format a series of cells (like in MS Word), built-in grouping and treeview, supports autofilter and printing via add-ons.

If I wrote a comparison chart for this grid and the grids above, I would definitely start from the price. iGrid is much cheaper but robust and very stable. The performance is also very good, even on slow tablets under Win7/Win8.

Comment: You might want to add a disclaimer stating that you are the person selling this product.

Comment: iGrid.NET is the best grid. I have tried them all extensively in production.